# Trigger event on text field with WebDriver execute script

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I have a text field that appends values to the dom once a user hits enter. I am having some trouble simulating this with WebDriver since driver.send_keys(:return) will just submit the form instead.

After looking at the way the text field is implemented, I noticed that it is looking for a 'keyup' event, and is using that to hit enter.

Using the browser console, I am successfully able to simulate this by triggering submit on a keyup event with jQuery in the following way:

```
var e = jQuery.Event('keyup') 
e.which = 13;
$('input').trigger(e)
```

Unfortunately, I can't accomplish this same thing with driver.execute_script. Any ideas why this isn't doing the trick?

```
driver.find_element(:id => 'input').send_keys('foo')
driver.execute_script("var e = jQuery.Event('keyup')")
driver.execute_script("e.which = 13;")
driver.execute_script("$('input').trigger(e)")
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this with Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium executes each javascript in a clousure and all variables defined in one execution are not available to the next executions. 
You should build your script first and execute it in one call:

`script = "var e = jQuery.Event('keyup'); e.which = 13; $('input').trigger(e)"
driver.execute_script(script)`

Comment: Makes sense. Calling it in one execution works. Thanks for the help!